# Using "owner = msg.sender" in a non-constructor function or in a declaration statement?

Tags: solidity

Will it be a problem to use :

```
 owner = msg.sender;
```

statement in a non-constructor function?

What if instead of writing the above code in a function, we initialize the owner at the time of declaration like this in a state variable:

```
address private owner = msg.sender;
```

Some body please guide me.

Zulfi.

Comment: Can you provide more context here? Are you using [ownable](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-solidity/blob/master/contracts/ownership/Ownable.sol) from OpenZeppelin? Or maybe your own version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the clarification in the comments to smarx's answer.

It depends what you mean by "problem". Consider this function.

```
function changeOwner() public {
  owner = msg.sender;
}
```

That allows anyone to seize the owner role, assuming `owner` is pivotal to access control somewhere else. That's not a problem in the sense that it works. That is a problem in the sense that anyone can do it and that's usually not desirable.

Consider this variant:

```
function changeOwner(address newOwner) public {
  require(msg.sender = owner);
  owner = newOwner;
}
```

The `require()` strictly limits this to the `owner`, so the sender has to be the owner in order to relinquish ownership. It doesn't make sense to relinquish to itself, so another address (the `newOwner`) is passed in. A production-ready implementation of this common pattern would check that the new address is valid to prevent accidents.

It may be helpful to remember that `owner` is not special in any way. It's merely a variable of type `address` given meaning by other aspects of the contract such as conditionals that oversee permission.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

**`owner = msg.sender;`
statement in a non-constructor function?**

> If you write `owner = msg.sender;` in a non-constructor function then 
>   1) You have to pay more gas amount(approx 1.5x more) as compared to we
>   deploy this statement using the constructor.
>
> 2) You need to call a function to set `owner = msg.sender` when you
>   are using the non-constructor function.

**What if instead of writing the above code in a function, we initialize the owner at the time of declaration like this in a state variable:**

> There is no problem with initializing owner at the time of declaration
>   but it changes the meaning of state variable for solidity compiler.
>   let me explain you:
>
> **Private:**
>
> When you declare `owner` as a `private state variable` like this
>   `address private owner = msg.sender;` then solidity compiler treat
>   owner variable as `variable` and for getting this variable value you
>   need to define another function like `getOwnerAddress()`.
>
> **Public:**
>
> If you set `owner` as public like this `address public owner = msg.sender;` then solidity compiler treat owner variable as `functionowner()` and this will also return the address value of owner there is
>   no need to define a separate function for getting value.

For more understanding, you can see a difference in `abi` of contract details.

Comment: Thanks. So : address private owner = msg.sender; as a declarative statement and in the same way: "owner = msg.sender ;" in constructor  is not vulnerable because most probably it would be done by owner at the time of creation of contract but function related statement: owner = msg,sender;" can be  vulnerable unless done in the manner as shown by Rob.

Comment: Yes, You are right. sorry, I take your question in another way.

Answer (score 0):

Statements aren't allowed outside of functions, but initializations are.

So your second snippet (`address private owner = msg.sender;`) is good.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for providing me these answers. I want to know if I provide the statement( owner = msg,sender)  in a non-constructor function, is it vulnerable, can any other account become the owner of contract? Similarly if i provide the statement as a declaration outside all functions, is it accessible to an adversary? Please guide me.

Comment: Sorry, I misread your question. You can assign to a state variable in any function. Whether this introduces a security vulnerability depends on what you use the variable for and who you allow to call that function. The initialization would only run once: at contract creation.